# Create random falling objects in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, entity

i am starting to learn unity3d and am developing a 2d game but need some help at the main menu. I have a coin texture which i would like to spawn multiple times above the screen and fall down to create a falling coin texture. Spawn points should be random and entities should be destroyed after falling off the screen, but i have no idea how to do it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Image Upload: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1rXM.jpg

Comment: Please try it yourself first, then post us your code. Questions of "Do this for me" are discouraged in the SO community, sorry my friend.

Comment: sorry about that, i had no idea. I really don't know where to start, as i am new to unity.

Comment: Try doing some online tutorials, there is a ton of online resources dedicated to learning Unity, however if someone here posts some code for you , you wont understand the underlying syntax behind what is in the code.

Comment: i understand C# basic, but unity does conversions between the GUI to the code behind it, its about what to do on the GUI that is the problem, not coding it in. I just cant find anywhere that does tutorials on something relating to my problem, if you could point me to a website it would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Ask yourself what problems you need to solve. Divide them up and solve each one individually. First You need a coin falling from the sky. Try placing one coin and have it fall from the sky. Once that works the way you want now try to get that coin to fall from a random location. Once you have achieved that try getting multiple coins to fall and reuse what you built to solve the first few problems. As you go you will realize that you have to solve smaller problems along the way. This is how development works. No body has a single answer or silver bullet to your unique problem unfortunately.

Comment: The proper tag for Unity3D is unity3d.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some starting points to done your task. You can read about`

1. RigidBody(RigidBody2D)
2. Collider(Collider2D)
3. MonoBehaviour Callbacks for example OnTriggerEnter(OnTriggerEnter2D) or OnCollisionEnter(OnCollisionEnter2D)
4. For randomness you can read about Random class and his methods like Random.randomInsideUnitCircle.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd start by reading up on Unity's particle system. By setting up some parameters in the editor it can exactly do what you want and very efficiently as well.

Some important parameters to consider:

1. Emitter shape: You want this to be a rectangle in your case, positioned at the top of the scene.
2. Initial velocity: You want this to be something like (0,-2,0) for downwards falling coins.
3. Emission rate: Determines how fast new coins will be produced.
4. Particle shape: Either a coin texture or a coin mesh or whatever you want.
5. Starting lifetime: The duration of each coin. The coin will be properly destroyed after this time.

The particle system will automatically choose random points within the emitter shape.

Answer (score 0):

Create a coin prefab with rigidbody2d and a collider component.
Create an empty game object, name it something like Spawner, and add the script bellow to it. (I named it Spawner)

```
  public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] GameObject coinPrefab;
private float minX = -10, maxX = 10; // change it
private float timeMin = 1, timeMax = 5; // change it
void Start()
{
    Invoke("SpawnCoins", Random.Range(timeMin, timeMax));
}
void SpawnCoins()
{
    float randPosx = Random.Range(minX, maxX);
    coinPrefab = Instantiate(coinPrefab, new Vector2(randPosx, transform.position.y), Quaternion.identity);
    Invoke("SpawnCoins", Random.Range(timeMin, timeMax));
}
```

}

I recommend you search what each function does. Check Unity manual.
To destroy the coins after hitting ground try use OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter function.

Also after being confident with the above, check object pooling.